# How to calculate the probability between two numbers from a probability distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, kernel-density

I've always thought it would be useful to calculate the probability between two values on a probability distribution. While there isn't a built-in way to do this using seaborn or matplotlib, I reckon it just takes some basic calculus, right? Here is some code I found from [an article on this topic](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-find-probability-from-probability-density-plots-7c392b218bab):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=1000000)

kd = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.5).fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1))

def get_probability(start_value, end_value, eval_points, kd):
    
    # Number of evaluation points 
    N = eval_points                                      
    step = (end_value - start_value) / (N - 1)  # Step size

    x = np.linspace(start_value, end_value, N)[:, np.newaxis]  # Generate values in the range
    kd_vals = np.exp(kd.score_samples(x))  # Get PDF values for each x
    probability = np.sum(kd_vals * step)  # Approximate the integral of the PDF
    return probability.round(4)

get_probability(x.mean() - x.std(), x.mean() + x.std(), 100, kd)

0.6338
```

This returns a probability that converges at 0.6338. This confused me, as the [68-95-99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) states that the probability of a value being within one standard deviation of the mean in either direction should be 68%.

I decided to run another test by calculating the probability between the median and max of a randomly generated sample, figuring it should converge close to 50%:

```
x = np.random.randint(100, size=(1000000))

# sns.kdeplot(x) # this is how  i'd generate a kdeplot of this data

kd = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.5).fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1))

def get_probability(start_value, end_value, eval_points, kd):
    
    # Number of evaluation points 
    N = eval_points                                      
    step = (end_value - start_value) / (N - 1)  # Step size

    x = np.linspace(start_value, end_value, N)[:, np.newaxis]  # Generate values in the range
    kd_vals = np.exp(kd.score_samples(x))  # Get PDF values for each x
    probability = np.sum(kd_vals * step)  # Approximate the integral of the PDF
    return probability.round(4)

get_probability(np.median(x), x.max(), 100, kd)

0.4946
```

And it's pretty close. Am I missing something here? Why am I nearly 5 percentage points off from the 68-95-99.7 rule? Is this method of generating probabilities from a probability distribution wrong? Is there a better way to find the probability between two values from a probability distribution?

*EDIT: Could you potentially calculate something by using the data generated from a kdeplot?*

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.kdeplot(x)
kdeline = ax.lines[0]
xs = kdeline.get_xdata()
ys = kdeline.get_ydata()
```

*And implement `np.interp()` somehow?*

More edits:

Using CDFs per @7shoe, I was able to get a way better (and correct) result for my normal distribution example:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

x = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=10000000)

norm.cdf(x.mean() + x.std()) - norm.cdf(x.mean() - x.std())
```

However, my curiosity is still piqued. Let's say we have a distribution that may or may not be normal. For example, let's look at Tom Brady's epa per pass from last season

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random
import numpy as np

YEAR = 2021

data = pd.read_csv(
    'https://github.com/nflverse/nflfastR-data/blob/master/data/play_by_play_' \
    + str(YEAR) + '.csv.gz?raw=True',compression='gzip', low_memory=False
    )

df = data.loc[data.passer == 'T.Brady','epa'].copy()

# tom brady's distribution
sns.kdeplot(df)

sample_mean = []

for i in range(50):
  y = np.random.choice(df, 500)
  avg = np.mean(y)
  sample_mean.append(avg)

# distribution of sampling means - can we assume this is normal and proceed with cdfs?
sns.kdeplot(sample_mean)
```

Could we use sampling means or even just bootstrap resampling methods to

1. Make a more "normal" distribution with sampling means in order to incorporate cdfs if the initial distribution doesn't quite appear normal (this, though, would be a distribution of means rather than individual samples. Is this not encouraged?)

or

2. If the distribution already resembles a normal distribution, simply use such resampling methods to create better parametric estimates?

Comment: It sounds like the term you're missing is the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing the probability `p` for some interval is not overly complicated. However, it might be tricky to combine the right tools to do so. In particular, since there are several statistical approaches to do so.

#### 1. Probability theory

Given two numbers, let's call them `lower` and `upper`, what probability is enclosed in between them? If the cumulative distribution function ([CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)) `F` is known, it is merely `p = F(upper) - F(lower)`. Similarly, `p` coincides with the area enclosed by the probability density function[(PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) `f`'s graph on the interval `[lower, upper]`.

However, when the CDF/PDF is unknown, it constitutes a statistical question. In a nutshell, estimating the PDF `f` and computing the area its graph enclosed with the interval will do. But there are several paradigms and estimation procedures to obtain it.

#### 1. Parametric estimation

One could assume that the data `x` is set of IID realizations of some normal distribution, either because of prior knowledge or convenience. Then, one just needs to estimate its parameters *mu* (aka `scale`) and `sigma` (aka standard deviation or `scale`). [`scipy.stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) provides all we need in this setting. Moreover, it offers estimation procedures as well as pdf/cdf functions for various parametric distributions.

```py
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

lower, upper = 0.0, 2.0
x = [-0.804, -2.267, 1.55, -1.004, 3.173, -0.522, -0.231, 3.95, -0.574, -0.213, 1.333, 2.42, 1.879, 3.814]

# fit parameter
loc_hat, scale_hat = stats.norm.fit(x)

# probability 
p = stats.norm.cdf(upper, loc=loc_hat, scale=scale_hat) - stats.norm.cdf(lower, loc=loc_hat, scale=scale_hat)

# plot 
x_axis = np.linspace(-5, 7, 1000)
plt.title('1. Parametric Estimation', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(x_axis, stats.norm.pdf(x_axis, loc_hat, scale_hat))
plt.fill_between(x  = np.arange(lower, upper, 0.01), 
                 y1 = stats.norm.pdf(np.arange(lower, upper, 0.01), loc=loc_hat, scale=scale_hat) ,
                 facecolor='red',
                 alpha=0.35)
plt.text(x=0.1, y=0.1, s= 'p=' + str(round(p, 3)))
plt.show()
```

which yields

[image]

#### 2. Non-parametric estimation

In the absence of a parametric assumption, various techniques exist to estimate the density directly (rather than identifying it by estimated parameters as seen above). Kernel density estimation is the most popular variant to do so. In this case, as alluded in the question, [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html) is an ideal tool. However, in the absence of an analytical CDF, we need to compute the area enclosed by the density's graph over the interval `[lower, upper]` directly.

In contrast to previous answers, I'd leave this to SciPy's numerical integration routines, e.g. [`scipy.inegrate.quad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html). The advantage is that it is lightning-fast and can be applied to any function (beyond kernel density estimates). The resulting code is as follows

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from scipy.integrate import quad

x = [-0.804, -2.267, 1.55, -1.004, 3.173, -0.522, -0.231, 3.95, -0.574, -0.213, 1.333, 2.42, 1.879, 3.814]

# fit density function
f_hat = KernelDensity(bandwidth=.9, kernel='gaussian').fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1))

def f_pred(x):
    '''wrapper function to compute probability'''
    return np.exp(f_hat.score_samples(np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)))[0]

p = quad(func=f_pred, a=lower, b=upper)

# plot
plt.title('2. Non-Parametric Estimation', fontsize=18)
xaxis = np.linspace(-5, 7, 1000)
plt.plot(x_axis, np.exp(f_hat.score_samples(xaxis.reshape(-1, 1))))
plt.fill_between(x  = np.arange(lower, upper, 0.01), 
                 y1 = np.exp(f_hat.score_samples(np.arange(lower, upper, 0.01).reshape(-1, 1))),
                 facecolor='red',
                 alpha=0.35)
plt.text(x=0.15, y=0.1, s= 'p=' + str(round(p[0], 3)))
plt.show()
```

and yields

[image]

Comment: Incredible. Thanks so much for this in depth answer. Using the cdfs I get a way better answer with a probability of .6827 for my normal distribution example. As you alluded to, for distributions that likely aren't safe to assume as normal (or as any other scipy distribution that has a cdf function ie binom, poisson etc) like the bimodal distribution in your example, that is when non-parametric methods should come into play? Got it. Also, in the case of assuming a distribution as normal like in your first example, would it be smart to bootstrap resample for better parametric estimates?See edits

Comment: Also, could you refer a  source explaining `f_pred` and how to get probabilities from the KernelDensity results? Is this essentially doing `e^log_likelihood`? I would like to learn more about this. Marked answer as correct btw.

Comment: Glad, it helped! I'd suggest the following. If you know the distribution, check out if it is listed in SciPy and use that CDF.  If you just got data `x` and you don't know anything about the data, try to narrow down what distribution it could be based on the values you observed in `x`. (1) Does the data look discrete or continuous? and then (2) does it look bounded or unbounded. E.g. If discrete, bounded (e.g. `{0,1,2,...,n}` or integer-values `{0,1,2,...}`. Or, if continuous `(-inf, inf)`, `[0, inf]`etc.

Comment: Regarding the `f_pred`. scikit-learn only provides the logarithm of the KDE function values, i.e. `log(f_n(x))` rather than the function value `f_n(x)` itself. See [reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.score_samples). In turn, we need to  do `np.exp(f_hat.score_samples(...))` Please note, hover that the function value of any (estimated or not) PDF is **not** the probability. Rather, the area the PDF's graph encloses with the x-axis on an interval is (indicated as a red-shaded area).

Answer (score 0):

I do see a bug in the `get_probability` function, but that bug causes it to compute a too *high* result - in `np.sum(kd_vals * step)`, it's multiplying N sample values by a step with `N-1` in the denominator, effectively resulting in an output a factor of `N/(N-1)` too high. (If they wanted to use a trapezoid rule computation for the integral, they should have divided the left and right endpoint values by 2 first.)

Other than that, the computation looks correct. The problem is that the model doesn't reflect the input distribution.

You're not modeling the distribution as a normal distribution. You're modeling it with a *kernel density estimator* with a Gaussian kernel, and the kernel bandwidth is very high relative to the scale of the distribution and the number of available samples. This results in the model being "flatter" than the actual distribution, with less of the probability concentrated in the center.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the insights! So, normal distributions aside, is there a "best" way to get the probability between any two values in a given probability distribution found in the wild?

Comment: The distribution found *in the wild* is never (truly) known. The Gaussianity assumption comes from your model as you chose `kernel=gaussian`.

Comment: @7shoe: Picking a Gaussian kernel doesn't mean assuming the distribution is Gaussian. It's a choice of how to smooth the model.

Comment: My bad. Indeed, the kernel choice merely defines the shape of each 'hat' being positioned on a data point. The resulting density (normalized sum over these 'hats') is almost surely not (even remotely) Gaussian. The classic mistake in kernel density estimation. Thank you for the correction.